# JFreeChart heap space

Tags: java, memory-management, jfreechart, visualvm

I'm just wondering if there's a way to stop JFreeChart thrashing the heap, or an alternative that doesn't do it so much. `SpreadsheetDate`, `Millisecond` and `Day` are taking up about 70 MB of the heap, but the garbage collector is probably getting thrashed too. They are, collectively, the biggest users of heap space in my app. There's also TimeSeriesDataItem which uses 12 MB. This is with recording things every 200 milliseconds or so, for all charts.

I'm also updating / storing a fair few datasets which aren't used immediately, only when the user clicks on the item in the UI to display them.

Also, is it possible in Visual VM to show much garbage collection thrashing is due to a particular class name in the memory sampler table?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: are you tried to run your project with JProfiler, there you can see all `Un-Closed Objects`

Comment: Would `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863), be an alternative? It profiles nicely at ~ 20 MB.

Comment: @mKorbel Will have a go with JProfiler, could be useful! I could have done with an academic license way back when..

Comment: Indeed, not JProfiler though.

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved this with a simple fix -- I now call `timeSeries.removeAgedItems(false)` after every `addOrUpdate` op. Works a treat, my heap usage is down :)